# Recommended Java (or Kotlin) serialization format for table-like data and random (indexed) read access?

Tags: java, serialization, indexing, deserialization

I have around ~50–100MB of data which consists of a list of structured objects. It is created once and I then want to efficiently read/find objects in it without having to deserialize it completely to memory when reading the resources.

Since I want to access objects randomly, I need some kind of index. I do not want to use a whole database approach like sqlite (I only need read access) and avoid 'heavy' dependencies.

Before I try to throw together my own, probably crappy serialization format, I was wondering if there are already good library I could use?

I found some interesting de/serialization formats like VelocyPack (https://github.com/arangodb/java-velocypack), but if I understood the API correctly, it allows efficient iterating over arrays, not random access. Even if I stored an index of some sort, it would not help here.

Comment: Use multiple files in a directory? It is a light solution for random access. You can desearlialize each element whenever you want.